# jest js manual mocking chained methods

Tags: node.js, npm, jestjs, unirest

I would like to manual mock with jest, the npm module unirest. I have created an `__mocks__` and placed unirest.js in there. I have created post method, and headers method but i keep getting this error. How do i create these chained methods and get the response.

> TypeError: unirest.post(...).headers is not a function

```
unirest
  .post('http://mockbin.com/request')
  .headers({'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
  .send({ "parameter": 23, "foo": "bar" })
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.body)
  })
```

this is the code in my `__mocks__/unirest.js`

```js
const unirest = jest.genMockFromModule('unirest');

const result = {
    data: 'theresponse'
};

const myheaders = {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'};

function headers(header) {
    header = myheaders;
    return header; 
}
console.log('inside uniREst promise mocker');

const post = opts => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return resolve(result); 
  });

  

unirest.post = post;
unirest.headers = headers


module.exports = unirest;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two options:

- mock every method of your test: That means, the first method called should return an object which contains a fake definition of the second one, that returns a definition of the third one and so on..
- use a mock object with a proxy!

Let's see the first approach: You would do something like this...

```
const FOO = 'something useful for your tests'
const send = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ body: FOO })
const headers = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ send })
const post = jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ headers })
jest.unirest = post
```

basically, it's a chain of functions: post returns an object with a function `headers`, which is a function that returns an object with a function `send` which resolves (not returns - resolves => meaning a promise that will return a value) to an object with a property body, that will resolve to whatever you want. Perhaps you want to customize that per test. Hope it works as a general guideline

[Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) allow you to execute a `get` method whenever you call something that's not defined. That would allow you to chain whatever method you want, and for the specific `send` return something useful.. it'd be something like this:

```
const handler = {
  get: (obj) => {
    return obj
  } 
}

const send = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({ body: FOO })
const target = { send } 
module.exports = new Proxy(target, handler)
```

Basically, whenever you call the unitest, it will try to execute that in target. If it exists, it will run the code. Otherwise, it will call the `get` function in the proxy, which basically will return the reference to itself (the parameter `obj`). I haven't used this approach but I believe it'd work - you basically mock  the functions you care in `target`, and for the rest, you just "do nothing". Perhaps this is useful if there is too much chaining and you don't care to do any assertion on all the middle functions.

Hope it provides some orientation.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const Foo = {body: 'My response from API'};

function end(response) { 
    return response(Foo);
}
     
const send = req => {
    return { end };
}

const headers = opt => {
    return { send };
};

const post = url => {
    return { headers };
};

console.log('Calling mock unirest');

module.exports = {
    post: post,
    headers: headers, 
    send: send, 
    end: end
}
```

Finally got it to work by using the following bit of code.Thanks for the help Gonzalo